# IIS ISAPI-DLL Handler gives internal 500 error in attempts to access the replaced DLL

Tags: asp.net, iis, isapi

We have an issue with our web site (IIS and ASP) and an ISAPI DLL.

We had to restore our web site (on an VM) from old(er) backup and ISAPI DLLs had to be replaced. We have also enabled 32 bit programs to execute under IIS.

But here is where things get ODD.

The ISAPI-dll handler does not work. That is, attempts to access the DLL we replaced give an internal 500 error.

The only way that we (read I) can ONLY get the ISAPI DLL to execute is if I add an entry into the Handler mapping section specifically for the DLL! And we did not do this previously.

But the DLL no longer recognise any of its standard actions. That is the internal path is returned as /lcnsmgr.dll/test rather than /test. And because of this the default action handler is always and only executed. While I could update all of the actions to include the dll name, we have never had to do this any time previously.

Logically, there is something wrong in the environment itself, but I cannot work out what that is. Looking for ideas how to resolve the issue with the ISAPI-dll handler and secondly the path issue mentioned above. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you cannot show the steps to reproduce the issue (and share that ISAPI executable), your only hope is to contact Microsoft support via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Did you put the dll in the network share folder? If it in network share folder, it won't work. By the way, the correct way to add ISAPI dll is use Handler Mapping, check the execute in edit feature permissions.